# spring-bootでの複数ファイルアップロードの進捗表示

Tags: java, spring-boot

spring-bootで複数のファイルを一括してアップロードする際に、個別で進捗を取得する方法はありますか？
総量の進捗も取得します。

※フォームを分割してアップロードするという方式は取りません。

```html
<html>
<form action="..." method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]"> or <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
...
```

- tips

  1. spring-boot: 2.4.x
  2. java: >= 11

Comment: 複数の解釈の余地がある質問になっているかなと感じます。アップロードの進捗を取得したいのは送信側(Webブラウザ)でしょうか、受信側(Spring Boot)でしょうか。「フォームを分割してアップロードするという方式は取りません」という注釈は、何を懸念して書かれたものでしょうか。 / 実現したいことも併記すると、他者が読んだときにイメージが掴みやすくなるかなと考えます。

Comment: 最終的には送信者側(Webブラウザ)での進捗表示が目的となります。ただ、方法として「SpringBoot側で1ファイル単位の進捗を取得しセッション経由で進捗をブラウザへ渡す実装しかないのでは」と考えています。また、「フォームを分割してアップロードするという方式は取りません」という注釈は複数ファイルを分割し、1ファイル単位のFormでアップロードすることによるjavascriptでのxhr progressイベント方式を排除するために記載致しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

アップロード済みファイルサイズの総量から、個別のファイルアップロード状況を逆算することで求められるかと思います。

```html
<html>
  <body>
<div>
  <form
    id="form"
    method="POST"
    enctype="multipart/form-data"
    action="/upload"
  >
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>File to upload:</td>
        <td><input id="input" type="file" name="files" multiple /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input id="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<script>
  const form = document.getElementById("form");
  form.addEventListener("submit", (ev) => {
    ev.preventDefault();
    const data = new FormData(form);
    const files = data.getAll("files");
    /* console.log(files); */

    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.upload.addEventListener("progress", (e) => {
      console.log(
        "TOTAL: " + ((100 * e.loaded) / e.total).toFixed(2) + "%"
      );

      /* アップロード済みサイズから各ファイルのアップロード状況を逆算 */
      let remain = e.loaded;
      for (const file of files) {
        if (file.size <= remain) {
          console.log(file.name + ": 100.00%");
          remain = remain - file.size;
        } else {
          console.log(
            file.name + ": " + ((100 * remain) / file.size).toFixed(2) + "%"
          );
          remain = 0;
        }
      }
    });
    request.open("POST", "/upload");
    request.send(data);
  });
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 仕様的にアップロードフォームを1つに固めることでアップロードサイズ制限をかけ、アップロードの進捗状況を個別・総量で表示（各ファイルは並列アップロード）を行いたかったのですが、1POSTリクエスト内のデータを並列で上げることはできないのですね。

Comment: 追加の情報があるのであれば、コメント欄でなく、質問文を更新されるのが良いかと思います。(更新があったことを他の人も知覚しやすいです) / 並列に送信するためには、クライアント=サーバ間に少なくとも2つのコネクションが必要かと思います(ので、1回のPOSTで行いたいという要求とは相反していると感じます)。